# for loop in django template - list object has not attribute 'get'

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

This seems like it must be very simple but I haven't been able to find an answer that address this specific problem. 
Essentially, I want my Django template to cycle through a list I made in that page's view. However when I try to run it I get "Attribute Error: 
'list' object has no attribute 'get'". I've been trying to expand upon the Django poll-app a little bit and the idea of this app is to have books, sorted by author, to vote on. So this view is going to show a table with the author's names on one side and the total number of votes from each of the author's books combined. 
Here are the models.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.author_name


class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is the view where I tried to group the votes by author and add them to a list.

```
def totals(request):
    a = Author.objects.order_by('author_name')
    b = Book.objects.order_by('author__author_name')
    total = []
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if i < len(b)-1:
            x = b[i].votes
            if b[i].author == b[i+1].author:
                x += b[i+1].votes
            else:
                total.append(x)
        else:
            x = b[i].votes
            total.append(x)
            return total

    return render(request, "book/totals.html", {"a":a, "total":total})
```

And here is the template. the first for loop on "a" works fine, its the second one that is supposed to cycle through "totals" that isn't working.

```
<h1>Total Votes</h1>
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"><strong>Totals</strong></th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">
        <th style="padding:5px;"><em>Authors</em></th>
        <th style="padding:5px;border-left:1px solid black;"><em>Votes</em></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    {% for author in a %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ author }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for x in total %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ total[x] }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</thead>
```

Ok I think that about does it. Thank you to anyone who read down this far. Obviously I'm pretty new to this so if there are any other comments or feedback anyone has I would certainly be grateful to hear them. 
Thanks!

Edit: Here is the traceback -

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/book/totals/

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'book')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  223.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py" in process_response
  31.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /book/totals/
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should return an HTTP response. However, your view returns `total`, which is a `list`.

```
         return total
```

You should either delete this line, or change it so it returns an HTTP  response.

Answer (score 1):

Please try using just x,  because x is an object not an index.

```
{% for x in total %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ x }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

I hope be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using "x" instead of "total[x]" and it still threw the "'list' object has no attribute 'get'" error.

Comment: @seeonsee share your full traceback